# Get the real size of base64Encoded image

Tags: swift

Is possible get the dimensions `width` and `height` of an image encoded as `base64Encoded` in swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert it back into an image from base64 string and get the size:

```
let strBase64 = "add valid base64 string here"

let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: strBase64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
let height = decodedimage?.size.height
let width = decodedimage?.size.width
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is possible get the dimensions width and height of an image encoded as base64Encoded in swift?

**Yes.** Decode the data, turn it into an image, and look at the image's dimensions.

If you don't want to go that far, you'll need to write some code that decodes at least the first part of the encoded data. Most image formats include a header of some sort that has the data you want. For example, a JPEG image starts with a [`_JFIFHeader`](https://www.fileformat.info/format/jpeg/egff.htm) that includes, among other things, the horizontal and vertical dimensions of the image. A PNG image contains a [`_IHDRChunk`](https://www.fileformat.info/format/png/egff.htm) that has similar info. So, if you know what type of image data you're dealing with, it should be pretty easy to just read the part you want and get the dimensions; if you need to support multiple image types, the task is a little harder because you have to figure out which type you're dealing with first.